# Is "import numpy as cp" good practice to handle non-GPU situations?

Tags: numpy, cupy

I'm writing code that is ideally run on the GPU for speed, using CuPy. However, I want the code to be able run (albeit more slowly) using a numpy implementation.
At the moment I am doing the following:

```py
import numpy as np
if gpu_present:
    import cupy as cp
else:
    import numpy as cp
```

I am worried that I might run into problems later on. Is this good practice?

Comment: [this](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/basic.html#how-to-write-cpu-gpu-agnostic-code) may be of interest

Answer (score 2):

When the script is small and the namespace to use can be fixed at the startup, I often use a global variable named `xp` (same as your solution). A similar pattern that I also sometimes use is to make it an instance attribute of a class (again named `xp`); it is more tolerable for future extensions because each instance can have a distinct value for that attribute. A similar, much more robust, but cumbersome approach is to make `xp` the first argument of every function.

When writing a library that may be used in any circumstances (e.g. multithreaded code, using both NumPy and CuPy in a single process), it is better to make each function/class handle the namespace appropriately for the arguments. I often use `get_array_module` utility for that purpose. [CuPy has this function](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.get_array_module.html?highlight=get_array_module), though it requires CuPy to be installed. [Chainer also has it](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.backend.get_array_module.html?highlight=get_array_module#chainer.backend.get_array_module). It is also simple to write by yourself. Using this utility, you can make the code usable with either NumPy or CuPy arrays without a global switch.

Also note that NumPy>=1.17 can dispatch CuPy arrays to appropriate CuPy routines, so you can pass CuPy arrays directly to `numpy.*` functions in most cases. If your code only does computation on given arrays, you even do not need to use `cupy` namespace at all (you still need to use it for creating a new array without giving another one, like `cupy.ones` and `cupy.random.*`).